# Basis presentation of minimization problem

Tags: optimization, hilbert-spaces

Let V be a Hilbert space, $V_0 \subset V$ a subspace (finite dimensional) and $f \in V_0$ and $g \in V$. I've got the minimization problem $min \{ \frac{1}{2} ||v||^2 - <f, v> \}$, where $v \in V_g$ for $V_g = g + V_0$ (which is an affine space).

Can you explain me, using a basis, how you can compute the basis-presentation of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making 
$$
v={\displaystyle \sum_{k}\alpha_{k}v_{k}+g}
$$

$$
f=\sum_{j}\beta_{j}v_{j}
$$

and assuming $\left\{ v_{k}\right\} $ as an orthonormal set, we have

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert v\right\Vert ^{2}-\left\langle f,v\right\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \sum_{k}\alpha_{k}v_{k}+g\right\Vert ^{2}-\left\langle \sum_{j}\beta_{j}v_{j},\sum_{k}\alpha_{k}v_{k}+g\right\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert \alpha_{k}^{2}\right\Vert +\frac{1}{2}\left\Vert g\right\Vert ^{2}+\sum_{k}\alpha_{k}\left\langle g,v_{k}\right\rangle -\sum_{k}\alpha_{k}\beta_{k}+\sum_{k}\beta_{k}\left\langle g,v_{k}\right\rangle 
$$

so the condition for stationary points is

$$
\alpha_{k}+\left\langle g,v_{k}\right\rangle -\beta_{k}=0
$$

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for! Thank you very much!